# Is it mulitple Key change?

Tags: theory, harmony, chord-progressions, key, modulation

Zion. T - Snow

**Chord progression:**

> Am7 - D7sus4 D7 - Gmaj7 - E7sus4 E7
>
> Am7 - D7sus4 D7 - Gmaj7 - E7sus4 E7
>
> Am7 Bm7 - Cmaj7 D7(9) - Gmaj7 - **Fmaj9 Fdim7**
>
> **(Interlude:)** Cm9 F13 - Bbm9 Eb6 - Am7 - D7

Right before interlude, he used Fmaj9 and Fdim7. I know that Fdim7 (Ddim7, Bdim7, or Abdim7) can resolve to half step up chords or a whole step below chords. But **where did Fmaj9 came from? Where does that belong to?**

---

My current thoughts are:

In the interlude, I think the key is changed from G to Bb to the Ab and back to G. So it is 2-5-1, not in BbM, but 2 in the key of Ab. So there is also 2-5.

Also, I discovered that Eb6 (Eb, G, C, Bb) and Am7(A, G, C, E) have same notes, G and C. And Eb and Bb is half step aeay from A and E.

Answer (score 1):

> Am7 - D7sus4 D7 - Gmaj7 - E7sus4 E7 x 2

Diatonic to a key signature of one sharp, `G` is a reasonable tonic. The `E7` is a secondary dominant to the `Am7`, assuming `x 2` means the progression repeats. Root progression by fifths.

> Am7 Bm7 - Cmaj7 D7(9) - Gmaj7

Also a tonic of `G`. Note the root progression by *steps*, not fifths, I think that may be relevant to the "interlude."

For the next stuff, *tonicize* may be a better description than "change key."

> Fmaj9 Fdim7 - (Interlude) Cm9...

...that tonicizes `C`, notice that `Fdim7` could also be called `Bdim7` which is often theoretically explained as an *incomplete* dominant seventh flat ninth chord, which would be a `G7b9`, the mode switches to minor, `Cm`, but that doesn't matter.

> ...F13 - Bbm9...

...tonicizes the `Bb`. In terms of keys it's "far" away from `G` major, but you could think of this as just a whole step down from `Cm`, sort of a sequential move.

If you accept the idea of `Cm` and `Bbm` as temporarily tonicized, notice that the change of tonics by step reflects the root progression by step in the earlier passage.

> ...Eb6...

...that chord makes sense as a subdominant of `Bb`, but it also could be an inversion of `Cm` which would just shift us back up to tonic `Cm`. Either chord, `Eb6` or `Cm7` can be viewed as a "borrowed" chord in `G` major, which is a way to get things back to `G`.

Note that from root `C` in `Cm9` to the `Eb` it's root progression by fifths. And if you regard the `Fdim7` as an incomplete `G7b9`, then it's descending fifths `G C F Bb Eb`.

It's important to recognize those roots by descending fifths, because it's a very important harmony concept, and the progression of roots is more important than the details of the chord qualities major/minor/etc.

> ...Am7 - D7...

That seems to bring us back to tonic `G`

The part you labeled "interlude" seems like a "B" section of a song which is where you often find sequential harmony or diversions to other tonics. Because those moments are of short duration, they sound temporary, and so *tonicize* can be a better description that "key change."

You would need to show more detail, especially about melody and phrasing to say more re. tonicize versus key change.

---

> ...But where did Fmaj9 came from? Where does that belong to?

At least by my description, I'm saying it comes from the tonic `C`. It's the subdominant of `C`, and it was arrived at *directly*, there was no *pivot chord*, or that kind of thing. Moving from an initial tonic of `G` to `C` is perfectly ordinary.

If there is confusion about an `F` major chord in relation to a `C` minor tonic, and the changing between the tones `A` natural and `A` flat, understand that this would all be described as *modal interchange* or *borrowed* harmony. The critical idea is chord roots and *tonal* scale degrees are the principle elements of tonality whereas modal chord and scale degrees are only elements of modal coloring.

Comment: In case it is of interest, I’ve penned down the harmonic structure of the complete piece in my answer.

Comment: I was think more along the lines of a lead sheet where you can see melody and bar lines.

Comment: Huh, you’re demanding ... Guess it’s somewhat like this http://petzel.at/sno.pdf

Comment: I'm not demanding anything of you @Lazy. I'm saying the chord list in your answer is not enough to make claims about phrasing which has bearing on key changes and such.

Comment: It’s not like I meant that seriously...

Comment: How am I supposed to know that? There are ways to convey a joke in comments.

Comment: I’m sorry, really! That’s just how I am, and probably the reason why I’m annoying everyone! Anyway, point is I’ve charted this out, if you want it.

Answer (score 0):

So this is somewhat the harmonic structure of the piece:

```
[INTRO]
Gmaj7(7) Cmaj7(3)
Gmaj7(7)/7 Cmaj7(3)
Bm7(3) em7(7)
Bm7(5-3) GP C/Em

[VERSE I]
Am7 D[4-3](9-8)
Gmaj7(7) E7[4-3]/7
Am7(7) D[5-8][4-3](5)
Gmaj7 E7[9-10]
Am7 D7
Gmaj7 E7[4-3][5-7]
Am7 Bm7 Cmaj7 D7
Gmaj7 → Fmaj7,9→Fo

Cm7,9 F7(6)
Bfm7,9 Ef7(6)
Am7,9 D7

[VERSE II]
Am7 D[4-3][9-8]
Gmaj7(7) E7[4-3]/7
Am7(7) D[5-8][4-3](5)
Gmaj7 E7[9-10]
Am7 D7
Gmaj7 E7[4-3][5-7]
Am7 Bm7 Cmaj7 D7
Gmaj7 E7

Am7 D7
G7 E7/[4-3]
Am7 D7

GP

Am7 D7
Gmaj7 E7
Am7 Bm7 Cmaj7 D7

Gmaj7 E7
Am7 D7
Gmaj7 E7
Am7 Bm7 Cmaj7 D7

Gmaj7 E7
Am7 D7
Gmaj7 E7
Am7 Bm7 Cmaj7 D7

Gmaj7 E7
```

As you can see the piece is somewhat in G major, with a very prominent `VI7-IIm` cadence. Also as the Verse starts on the IIm this gives us a somewhat unclear tonic, with both G major and A minor taking a tonic like character.

The most prominent figure here is a short altered chain of fifths in the form `II-V-I-VI7-(II)`.

Now, in the interlude we get `Fmaj9→Fo`, which does not stand on it’s own, but is superimposed on the previous `Gmaj7`.

This thus creates the harmonic effect of `Gmaj7→G7,9,11,13→G7,b9` and thus an secundary dominant on the tonic. In fact this `Fo` can be seen as `Bo`, which simply makes it the classic diminished substitution for the Dominant `G7` (in german we call this DV, a `V7,b9` chord with omitted root, and one of the standard functions of a diminished 7th chord).

This secondary dominant then resolves correctly into the `IV`, but in minor. So we get a harmonic change to the `IV` but in minor, which is c minor. From there we get a modulating chain of 5ths (instead of a diatonic chain of fiths that would eventually lead us back to g minor). This means we get a sequence of pairs (dominant chord → non dominant chord), which forces the use of pure fifths and would eventually traverse the whole circle of fifths (it can be seen as a chain of `V7→I=II→V7→I=II→...`, so the Bf minor is simply a piece of the chain).

But this chain is cut short, and instead of going into Af we directly go back to A minor, leading us back to G major.

So instead of taking this as key changes I’d say it is a somewhat weird modulation of mode, from G major to G minor and back to G major. For a key change we’d need to have a change of tonic, but this section does not establish a true new tonic, the ear does expect a modulation back to either G (the tonic) or C (the subdominant). Just we’d rather expect to hear something like `G7 | Cm7 F7 | Bfm7 Ef7 | Aø D7 | G`, leading to the tonic, or `G7 | Cm7 F7 | Bfm7 Ef7 | Afmaj7 Dø | G7 | Cm`, leading back to the subdominant. Instead we get this unexpected `Ef7 | Am7 D7`.

EDIT: I’ve charted this out, for anyone who is interested, look here:
http://petzel.at/sno.pdf

Comment: Given how common E7-Am7 and D7-Am7 are in the rest of the piece, I'd say **only the introduction is in G major** and **the rest of the piece** (except for the Cm7,9 F7(6) Bbm7,9 Eb7(6) passage) **is in A minor**. The piece ending with an E7 chord instead of a G or even D chord also supports the piece after the introduction and other than the Cm7,9 F7(6) Bbm7,9 Eb7(6) passage being in A minor, as E7 is V7 in A minor (and ending the piece on the dominant is one of the most common unresolved endings, in my experience).

Comment: @Dekkadeci As I stated the tonic is very unclear, as we get two very prominent cadences. `E7-Am` is not really more common than `D7-G`, rather we get some sort of cycle `Am-D7-G-E7-Am-D7-G-...`. In fact if we factor out the dominants the basic chord structure we get is `Am-G` repeated. Switching between two neighboring steps seems to be a very common thing in modern pop music. Still I’d put this as G major, as the final cadence of each structural section is a `D7-G`. The full base cadence for this seems to be `I-VI7-II-V7-I`, as clearly stated in the end.

Comment: No, the final cadence of each structural section is not D7-G. Taking every single double line break as a section break, we get C/Em, then D7-Gmaj7 → Fmaj7,9→Fo, then Eb7(6)-Am7,9-D7, then D7-Gmaj7-D7, then E7/[4-3]-Am7-D7, then Cmaj7-D7 three times in a row, and finally Gmaj7-E7. (Taking only labels such as Verse II as section indicators gets silly quickly due to there being only 3 such labels and the majority of the chords being after the last label.) Even with a different section indicator system that ignores more double line breaks, E7/[4-3]-Am7-D7 still isn't a D7-G cadence.

Comment: While the Am7-D7-Gmaj7-E7 cycle exists, the simplest interpretation of it involves as few secondary dominants and tonicizations as possible. Keeping the entire cycle in A minor pulls that off while still remaining reasonably within common practice period harmony, while keeping the entire cycle in G major fails to explain  the E7 chords, and assigning E7-Am7 to A minor and D7-Gmaj7 to G major involves too many tonicizations(/modulations).

Comment: @Dekkadeci Are you serious? `E7` is to G the triple dominant `VVV`, that is the dominant to the dominant to the dominant. Meanwhile `D7` is the dominant to G, which is the `VII` of A minor, which is not a particularly common chord. Also let me count out to you: Each verse ends on a cadence `D7→Gmaj7`, the interludes end on a dominant `D7`, and all these loops in the end end with a `D7` dominant.

Comment: I'd call a triple dominant - that is, V/V/V - a type of secondary dominant. With no chord extensions, it sounds identical to V/ii. VII is a pretty common chord in minor keys (well, at least in classical music). I've heard pieces change keys every 2 measures - they were *all* a lot more blatant about changing keys than the piece in the question (e.g. piece changed between *chromatic mediants* every 2 measures). I cannot think of Am7-D7-Gmaj7-E7 as changing keys every 2 chords when we can interpret it with common practice period harmony rules in exactly 1 key.

Comment: I also may as well emphasize again that the piece has D7-Am7 appear at least twice - a chord progression unheard of in G major in common practice period harmony. (It is V7-ii7 in G major, which isn't even an acceptable deceptive cadence.) This is one of the strongest features convincing me that the piece after the introduction is in A minor and not G major, as D7-Am7 is the far more acceptable IV7-i7 in A minor (even if common practice period harmony never liked i7).

Comment: @Dekkadeci This is just an unresolved dominant. And yes they happend in two places: After the first interlude, which ends on the dominant `D`as one would expect. Then the following verse just starts on the `II` instead of the `I`, which leads to this unresolved dominant. The second case is after the piece has some sort of half end the dominant `D` (as expected), a GP and then starts again with a coda, starting again on the `II`.

Comment: I didn't count the one with the GP in between. The D7-Am7 appearances I was counting are the one straddling the Verse II header and the one straddling the first double line break after the Verse II header.

Comment: @Dekkadeci I must ask, have you ever listened to the piece? It seems like you want to make a point just by looking at a few chord changes. I have listened to the piece quite a bit to chart it out http://petzel.at/sno.pdf so I am quite sure which cadenzas feel like tonic resolutions and which do not.

Comment: @Dekkadeci I’m sorry, that was a mess up by me, that one is actually an `E7`, as can be seen in the chart.

Comment: Yes, I actually did yesterday. Might be my ear buds, but #1: The piece actually sounded a lot more like it was in G major than I thought from the chord analysis, but the E7-Am7 always made me doubt that G major is the right call, and #2: Several of the Am7, especially the ones immediately following D7, actually sounded like Am7/G and I therefore interpreted them as G chords of some sort, and #3: The Cm7, 9 chord actually sounded like Eb13/Eb (i.e. an extended Eb chord) and therefore weakened the seeming Cm -> Bbm progression in the most modulatory part.

Answer (score -3):

Assuming all the chord progressions you provided are correct, and without listening to the piece...

The chord progression Am7 - D7sus4 D7 - Gmaj7 - E7sus4 E7 x 2 Am7 Bm7 - Cmaj7 D7(9) - Gmaj7 - Fmaj9 is actually in **A minor**, not G major. The E -> Am general chord progression at the E7 x 2 Am7 section and the fact that the chord progression starts with Am7 are both strong giveaways that the chord progression is in A minor. The D7 - Gmaj7 and D7(9) - Gmaj7, regardless of their resemblance to a V-I chord progression in G major, can be interpreted as a mere IV7-VII7 in A minor.

The Fmaj9 chord at the end can therefore be interpreted as VI9 in A minor, since A minor includes both F natural and F♯.

The Cm9 F13 - Bbm9 Eb6 - Am7 - D7 section is trickier to interpret, but assuming there is a key change from C minor to B flat minor in the first 4 chords (and strong parallelism) is a more solid interpretation than assuming all 4 chords are in B flat minor due to F13 containing D natural. The Am7 - D7 wrenches us back into A minor due to a similar chord progression being used at the very beginning of the piece.

The key change from C minor to B flat minor is facilitated by Cm9 F13 - Bbm9 sounding a lot like a ii-V-i chord progression in B flat minor. Bbm9 Eb6 similarly sounds like ii-V in A flat major...but the chord progression never reaches an Ab chord, so I hesitate to say the piece ever goes to A flat major. Note that Cm9 F13 - Bbm9 Eb6 can be interpreted as Cm: i9 -> IV13 = Bbm: V♮13 -> i9 -> IV"6" (note that IV6 actually stands for IV in first inversion).

You are right that Eb6 (Eb, G, C, Bb) and Am7(A, G, C, E) share G and C, and Eb and Bb are a half step away from A and E, so the voice leading between Eb6 and Am7 is shockingly smooth and eases that otherwise (more) jarring transition.